# How to write Bigquery for below table

Tags: google-bigquery

*The output should be count of max items sold in a date.*
**This is bigquery table:**

```
item,date
apple,1-1-2020
apple,1-1-2020
pear,1-1-2020
pear,1-1-2020
pear,1-2-2020
pear,1-2-2020
pear,1-2-2020
orange,1-2-2020
```

**Expected output:**

```
item,date
apple,1-1-2020
pear,1-1-2020
pear,1-2-2020
```

Comment: Please post your own queries, even if they failed. As the question stands now, it will not be useful to others, because you have not explained the problem you are struggling with.

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach

```
select item, date, count(1) sales
from `project.dataset.table`
group by item, date
qualify rank() over(partition by date order by sales desc) = 1
```

When applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

If for some reason, you don't want to have sales column in your output - use below

```
select item, date
from `project.dataset.table`
group by item, date
qualify rank() over(partition by date order by count(1) desc) = 1
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The following query should do it:

```
SELECT
  item,
  sale_date,
FROM (
  SELECT
    sample.*,
    COUNT(item) AS item_count
  FROM
    sample
  GROUP BY
    sample.sale_date,
    item )
    # Here you need to use a WHERE (or HAVING, or GROUP BY) in order to be able to use QUALIFY
    WHERE sale_date IS NOT NULL
  QUALIFY RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY sale_date ORDER BY item_count DESC)  = 1
```